# Node.js MongoDB collection.find().toArray returns nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Although I found similar questions to mine, I couldn't solve the problem on my own.

In my '../models/user' model I want to find all users and put them into array, and return that array to the controller(where I will use the info).

Here is my code:

```
var mongoDatabase = require('../db');
var database = mongoDatabase.getDb();

function find() {
    var test;
    database.collection("customers").find().toArray( function(err, docs) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(docs); //works fine
         //I'd like to return docs array to the caller
        test = docs;
    });

    console.log(test); //test is undefined  
}

module.exports = {
    find
};
```

I also noticed, that 'console.log(test)' goes before 'console.log(docs)'. I tried passing 'docs' argument as function parameter to 'find', but without result.

Comment: Judging from the documents of MongoDB you cannot pass arguments to the toArray why don't you simply do ```test = database.customers.find().toArray()```

Comment: @Ozan still undefined

Comment: @Petar D. Well I just tested in my local development and it did return all the documents. I am not sure what's causing it. Why don't you use mongoose ?

Comment: @Ozan I'll start using Mongoose soon, but first I'd like to learn the basics

Comment: You can try this, 
var mongoDatabase = require('../db');
var database = mongoDatabase.getDb();

function find() {
    return database.collection("customers").find().toArray();
}
 module.exports = {
    find
};

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way is to use Promises. Do it like this.

```
function getUsers () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     database.collection("customers").find().toArray( function(err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        // Reject the Promise with an error
        return reject(err)
      }

      // Resolve (or fulfill) the promise with data
      return resolve(docs)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: What modules should I include? Is that 'jQuery'?

Comment: No, I have edited it, You should install an npm module 'q'

Comment: There is no need to add yet another module as Node.js has been supporting native Promises since around version 0.12 by itself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @PetarD. You can also use the above code if you don't want to include the module

Comment: @Kamesh thank you, now the last thing I want to do is: 'var usersInfo = users.find(); console.log(usersInfo');' and it says 'Promise {<pending>'}. Can you help with that too :D

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Where are you writing these statements?

Comment: In my router, 
'router.get('/', function(req, res) {
 var usersInfo = users.find();
console.log(usersInfo); 
res.render("myview", { data: usersInfo });
}'

Comment: Is users a mongo model? In that case you need to have a callback in your find as well. users.find(function(err, docs){ //resolve promise here with your data })

Comment: but If we console the docs it will say undefine.

Comment: That is why you need to use console.log inside the definition for function passed to toArray

Comment: How can i write this in python3? @Kamesh