# trying to get the array result for mongodb in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get a result from MongoDB database return as a response for my GET Request when I make the call  I'm getting undefined in the response, I'm able to see the result in console log on the database side of the code. I'm feeling like it might have something to do with it being an array

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb'),
  mongodburl = "mongodb://localhost:27017",
  mongo = require('mongodb'),
  assert = require('assert');


let method={}
method.insertdata=function(data,collectionpara) {
  MongoClient.connect(mongodburl, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    let dbo = db.db("hor-usData");
    let myobj = data;
    dbo.collection(collectionpara).insert(myobj, function (err, result) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log("insert data");
      db.close();
    })
  })
}

method.deleteRecords=function(collectionpara) {
  MongoClient.connect(mongodburl, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    let dbo = db.db("hor-usData");
    var myquery = {
      title: /^B/
    };
    dbo.collection(collectionpara).deleteMany(myquery, function (err, obj) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(obj.result.n + " document(s) deleted");
      db.close();
    })
  })
}
method.getdata=function(collectionpara){
  MongoClient.connect(mongodburl, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let dbo = db.db("hor-usData");
    dbo.collection(collectionpara).find().toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err){
        return reject(err)
      }
      console.log('result',result);
      return resolve(result);
    });
  });  
}

module.exports = method;
```

### and my router code

```
let assert = require('assert'),
    express = require('express'),
    router = express(),
    swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express'),
    database=require('../databaseCon'),
   // swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json'),
    utils = require('../utils/utils');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


//get donedeal
router.get('/getDonedeal', function (req, res, next) {
    let donedealResult = []
    donedealResult=database.getdata('donedeal');
    res.send(donedealResult);
});

//get carzone
router.get('/getCarzone', function (req, res, next) {
    let carzoneResult = [];
    carzoneResult=database.getdata('carzone');
    res.send(console.log(carzoneResult));
});


router.get('/cars', function (req, res, next) {
    res.router('Mainrouter')
});

router.get('/getCarzone', function (req, res, next) {
    var resultArray = []
});
router.listen(port);
//app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
//app.use('/api/v1', router);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It has already been answered on this post : [Node.js MongoDB collection.find().toArray returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118957/node-js-mongodb-collection-find-toarray-returns-nothing)

Comment: the problem I'm having seems to be more on the express side, I can data no problem but getting the data to show when I make API call is not working

Comment: @Sense is right: your answer is in the validated answer of the linked post. Your `method.getdata` should return a promise (instead of implicitly returning `undefined`), and this promise should be resolved with `result`, inside `toArray`'s callback.

Comment: @Sense, I update the database code, I'm still getting the same error on the express side when I made the /getDonedeal call it showing as undefine

Comment: You did not create any Promise in your `getdata` function, so you can't `resolve` or `reject` anything. Please read carefully the link I provided earlier.